# CSV data Import into neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a data in my excel sheet like the screenshot below: 
[image]

but i want to import it with relationship into neo4j like this:
[image]
So can some one please guide me how to do this with neo4j Thanks

Comment: what query you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your data into a proper csv format first. That means something like this:
[image: proper csv format]

Once you have that you can easily do something like

> load csv from <> as csv
> merge (n1:Node {name: csv.start})
> merge (n2:Node {name: csv.end})
> merge (n1)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(n2);

Maybe you can try that?

Comment: Thank i can try this method before .. But if i can do this then how can i remove redundancy and in above mention csv pic how can i create relationship between 3 and 5, 6 as there is null in 5 and 6 row..

Comment: I would first write an excel macro to transform your table into a list of rels. And then the csv import will be much simpler (as Rik mentioned) Using the macro you can ensure there is no duplicates.